# Apex trigger to update fields (lookup and date) at asset object from custom object

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom lookup field `Asset__c`  on custom object `Service_Report__c.  Service_Report__c` is a child object of standard `case` object i.e. `case` is parent of `Service_Report__c`

Now I want to write an apex trigger to update `InstallDate` and `Site__c` fields on the **Asset** `if Asset__c!=null`, when I create and update record of custom object  `Service_Report__c`.

```
InstallDate(asset) = Date_of_Site_Visit_To__c(custom lookup field at Service_Report__c)
Site__c(custom lookup field at asset) =  Site__c(custom lookup field at case)
Asset object fields: InstallDate(Standard field),  Site__c(lookup)
Service_Report__c  object fields: Case__c(lookup), Asset__c(lookup), Date_of_Site_Visit_To__c(date field)
Case object fields: Site__c(lookup)
```

Comment: As you've not included any of the basics I'd expect to see in a trigger in your code, I recommend you start by going through the [Apex Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.htm), then come back and ask for more assistance.

Comment: Have you thought about using the process builder for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Process Builder or Flow for this.  It seems that you can get away with Process Builder with how basic your solution is.  Simply set your Process Builder to be triggered on the Service_Report__c Object, and then make your 'reqs' that Asset__c != null. Grab a Record Update.  Select the Service_Report__c Object (clicking on the name, its confusing at first).  After you do that, bring in your two fields "InstallDate" and "Site".  From there, make the way they are updated Referenced... and grab the two Asset fields as the values you want to update with.  Should be pretty easy. If you get too much more complex you can look at using a Flow.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply David. Here I have an issue that Process Builder currently does not allow me to edit a deactivated process. Here I also want to know that what is the basic diffference between process builder and flow.

Comment: Krishan, you need to CLONE the Process Builder that you want to Edit.  After a Process Builder has been 'activated' once, it is 'static' and cant be edited.  So, Clone the PB and then make your edits.

Comment: The difference between Process Builder and Flow is --- Process Builder IS a Flow with a different UI, and Process Builder can 'trigger' a Flow to run.  A Process Builder is a limited version of a Flow, but it provides the everyday admin a really really easy way to make updates.  So knowing both is quite a good idea, as Process Builder is just another form of Flow, so any advancements to Process Builder's abilities will also improve Flow, since they are the same.